# Apple Mail Email Signature - Tables Collapsing/Overlapping on Each Other?

Tags: html, ios, html-email, apple-mail

Occasionally, I get notified of issues from clients that the HTML email signature I created for them is collapsing upon itself in the default Apple Mail app on iOS.

This tends to only occur when I implement multiple tables on top of each other, which is necessary for designs such as the one below in order to ensure one of the tables has a complete background color, with no hairlines of white in between table cells.

Anyway, what seems to happen is the tables collapse upon each other, but I can't replicate the issue on my iPad 3 running iOS 9.3.5, which is the only Mac device I own and can test installing and sending from (I use Email on Acid to test receiving on multiple devices and platforms).

Below is an example of the issue and the underlying code... Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

How it should look vs how it sometimes looks from Apple Mail on iOS:

[image: How it should look vs how it sometimes looks from Apple Mail on iOS]

And here's the code for this example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <table width="425" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="130" rowspan="4" valign="bottom" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px; vertical-align: bottom;"><img alt="Headshot" height="120" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Tony-Ashmore-Headshot-v2.png" style="display: inline-block;" width="120"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="295" style="padding: 5px 0px 1px 0px;"><img alt="Signature" height="55" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Tony-Ashmore-Signature-v1.png" style="display: inline-block;" width="50"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="295" valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 0px; border-bottom: #00aeef 1px dotted; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 15px; color: #3a3a3c;"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 11pt;">Tony Ashmore</span> <span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 8pt; color: #00aeef;">REAL ESTATE PROFESSIONAL</span>
   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="295" valign="bottom" style="padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #3a3a3c; line-height: 15px; vertical-align: bottom;">
  <div nowrap style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <span style="color: #00aeef; font-weight: bold; font-size: 6pt;">M</span> <a href="tel:345-324-3333" style="border: none; text-decoration: none; color: #3a3a3c; font-weight: bold;">345 324 3333</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #00aeef; font-weight: bold;">&bull;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:Tony@AshmoreAlexander.com" style="border: none; text-decoration: none; color: #00aeef;">Tony@AshmoreAlexander.com</a><br>
  <span style="color: #3a3a3c;">P.O. Box 31673, Grand Cayman KY&zwnj;1-12&zwnj;07, Cayman Islands</span><br>
  <a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none; color: #00aeef; font-weight: bold;">www.AshmoreAlexander.com</a>
  </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="130" height="10" style="font-size: 10px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="295" height="10" style="font-size: 10px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table bgcolor="#00aeef" width="425" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #00aeef;">
  <tbody>
 <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="200" height="1" style="border-top: #3a3a3c 1px solid; font-size: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="225" height="1" style="border-top: #3a3a3c 1px solid; font-size: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="250" height="46" bgcolor="#00aeef" valign="middle" rowspan="2" style="padding: 8px 0px 5px 10px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #00aeef;"><a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Logo" height="50" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Logo-White-v2.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="195"></a></td>
      <td width="175" height="23" bgcolor="#00aeef" align="right" valign="bottom" style="padding: 8px 10px 1px 0px; vertical-align: bottom; background-color: #00aeef;"><a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/cayman-islands-real-estate-for-sale/"><img alt="Properties For Sale" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-For-Sale-Button-v2.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="165"></a>
   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="210" height="23" bgcolor="#00aeef" align="right" valign="top" style="padding: 2px 10px 5px 0px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #00aeef;"><a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/contact-us/"><img alt="What's Your Home Worth?" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Worth-Button-v1.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="165"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="425" colspan="2" height="5" bgcolor="#3a3a3c" style="background-color: #3a3a3c; font-size: 5px; line-height: 5px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table width="425" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td width="125" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; vertical-align: top;">
   <a href="https://business.facebook.com/CaymanIslandsRealEstateAshmoreAlexander/?business_id=1389844441340315" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Facebook.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/ashmorealexander/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Instagram" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Instagram.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tonyashmore/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Linkedin" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Linkedin.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/TheTonyAshmore" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Twitter.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a></td>
   <td width="300" valign="top" align="right" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; vertical-align: top;"><img alt="CIREBA MLS Regal Realty" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-cireba_mls_regal-realty.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="267"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <table width="auto" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;"><img alt="Think before you print" height="12" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Think-v1.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="128"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You using heights on td's, colspan and rowspan. Try to stay away from them

Answer (score 0):

Like i said in my above comment, you are using heights on td's, rowspan and colspan. Try to stay away from them. I have recoded bits and pieces of your HTML and added a few more things.

```html
<table width="425" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td width="120" valign="bottom" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px; vertical-align: bottom;"><img alt="Headshot" height="120" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Tony-Ashmore-Headshot-v2.png" style="display: inline-block;" width="120"></td>
             <td width="295" valign="bottom"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td style="padding: 5px 0px 1px 0px;"><img alt="Signature" height="55" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Tony-Ashmore-Signature-v1.png" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
                    </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 0px; border-bottom: #00aeef 1px dotted; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 15px; color: #3a3a3c;"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 11pt;">Tony Ashmore</span> <span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 8pt; color: #00aeef;">REAL ESTATE PROFESSIONAL</span></td>
                    </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td valign="bottom" style="padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #3a3a3c; line-height: 15px; vertical-align: bottom;"><div nowrap style="white-space: nowrap;"> <span style="color: #00aeef; font-weight: bold; font-size: 6pt;">M</span> <a href="tel:345-324-3333" style="border: none; text-decoration: none; color: #3a3a3c; font-weight: bold;">345 324 3333</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #00aeef; font-weight: bold;">&bull;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:Tony@AshmoreAlexander.com" style="border: none; text-decoration: none; color: #00aeef;">Tony@AshmoreAlexander.com</a><br>
                     <span style="color: #3a3a3c;">P.O. Box 31673, Grand Cayman KY&zwnj;1-12&zwnj;07, Cayman Islands</span><br>
                     <a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none; color: #00aeef; font-weight: bold;">www.AshmoreAlexander.com</a></div></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
            <table bgcolor="#00aeef" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #00aeef;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="200" height="1" style="border-top: #3a3a3c 1px solid; font-size: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="225" height="1" style="border-top: #3a3a3c 1px solid; font-size: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" bgcolor="#00aeef" valign="middle" style="padding: 8px 0px 5px 10px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #00aeef;"><a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Logo" height="50" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Logo-White-v2.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="195"></a></td>
                  <td bgcolor="#00aeef" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 8px 10px 1px 0px; vertical-align: bottom; background-color: #00aeef;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#00aeef" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #00aeef;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#00aeef" align="right" valign="bottom" style="padding: 8px 10px 1px 0px; vertical-align: bottom; background-color: #00aeef;"><a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/cayman-islands-real-estate-for-sale/"><img alt="Properties For Sale" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-For-Sale-Button-v2.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="165"></a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#00aeef" align="right" valign="top" style="padding: 2px 10px 5px 0px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #00aeef;"><a href="http://www.ashmorealexander.com/contact-us/"><img alt="What's Your Home Worth?" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Worth-Button-v1.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="165"></a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="125" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; vertical-align: top;"><a href="https://business.facebook.com/CaymanIslandsRealEstateAshmoreAlexander/?business_id=1389844441340315" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Facebook.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/ashmorealexander/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Instagram" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Instagram.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tonyashmore/" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Linkedin" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Linkedin.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/TheTonyAshmore" style="border: none; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Twitter.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="22"></a></td>
                  <td width="300" valign="top" align="right" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; vertical-align: top;"><img alt="CIREBA MLS Regal Realty" height="22" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-cireba_mls_regal-realty.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="267"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;"><img alt="Think before you print" height="12" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/makalla/Ashmore+Alexander/AA-Think-v1.png" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0;" width="128"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this works for you.